# slight cracking in mortar between clay tile flue in fireplace

Tags: fireplace

We have a fireplace that is about 40 years old.  Draws well and exterior is perfect.  Had it inspected and discovered slight cracks in the mortar between the clay tile lining the flu.  Is there a simple and easy way to repair this?  And are minor cracks (hairline) in mortar dangerous.  The tiles themselves are perfect other than a little dirty.

Comment: I think what would be unusual would be no hairline cracks in this location.

Answer (score 0):

There's no magic fix.    Get a fireplace/flue specialist out to give their opinion.  They'll tell you if it's safe to keep in service, or the appropriate repair procedure.